# How does android treat a background image in Android?

Tags: java, android, background

How is this done?

For example, if I were to set the background at a .png file I created for a custom background, what happens during the different screen sizes? How would I make a custom background be dynamic to where it will grow and shrink without looking horrible across multiple screens?

Any help is appreciated. I've been studying and working with android for a few weeks now and have experience in java, I am getting the programming, I just don't know how the graphic design aspect of an application works so this is new to me. I've never created anything that required a custom background or any type of custom graphic before.. thanks!

Comment: [This might of something interesting for you](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete explanation in Android Documentation [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed. I've been glued to d.android.com since I've started along with a few books, so I'm on information overload.

Comment: @tbaldw02: now you can mark this answer as correct. (*i.e tick this as accepted*). This will increase your points.